# Restfulness when submitting a resource with associated tags

Tags: rest

I have the concept of a Tag. The system have several tags, and they can be fetched at /tags.

A tag consist of the ID and a Name.

When a User submits a House, he can add several tags to it, so a JSON for a submitted House, could be like:

```
{"house" : { "name" : "White House", "tags" : [8,10,9] } }
```

Where 8,10,9 would be the IDs of the tags.

However, would it be RESTful if I would let the users to provide the names of the tags? Like:

```
{"house" : { "name" : "White House", "tags" : ['big','residential','garden'] } }
```

I don't see the advantages of using text besides that it is more self explanatory. Would this be a good solution, or at least RESTful?

Comment: RESTfulness has to do with the way data is queried, created, and updated and less to do with the structure of the data.  e.g. using the right verbs and providing links to urls for state transitions in certain results.  Having the user provide tag values is never more RESTful nor less RESTful based on the way you've described it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both syntax. Your REST client does not care, it is a machine, not a person.

The uniform interface constraint of REST is about decoupling the client from the implementation of the service. The implementation of the service consists mostly of URI structures, data structures, etc... To decouple the client from these things you have to use standards:

- the URI standard to indentify a resource,
- the HTTP standard to define methods in order to manipulate resources,
- standard MIME types to describe the serialization formats of each message,
- links to describe the available operations and decouple the client from the URI structure,
- standard vocabs to add semantics to links (e.g. link relations)
- standard vocabs to add semantics to data structures (e.g. RDF vocabs)

In your case submitting the house is an operation which you can describe as a link in a response. So by processing that resource your client will be able to generate a form. You can add fields to your link for example tags. You can add semantics and range to that field, for example index or name with the proper annotations, so your client will be able to automatically download the list of available tags, etc... In order to do this you need an RDF compatible MIME type, for example JSON-LD and a vocab which can describe links, like Hydra.

If you don't write your API for 3rd party clients, then you probably don't need all of these. In that case to fulfill the uniform interface constraint it is enough to define your vendor specific MIME type (which can contain links), and do what you want. Just be aware that your client will easily break by any change of the service. There are hypermedia types which can be a good template, for example HAL, collection+json, shiren, etc...